# Observable<Object[]> - Can I skip/take?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, infinite-scroll

I want to imlpement infinite-scrolling on my list of objects, they are `Observable<Object[]>`. Transferring them to promise and `await`ing them is not an option since they need to be updated in realtime.

What I did is used `.map()` which kind-of works, but the problem is that angular is re-rendering the whole list whenever I take `20` items instead of `10` for example.

One solution would be to actually skip first `10` and load next `10` which would only add new elements to the page. However I'm not sure if it is possible?

Here is what I have

Typescript

```
// Every time this happens page goes to top
// because all the items are re-rendered, not only new ones
public onScroll(): void {
  this.take += 10; // on ngOnInit() take is set to 10.
  this.sales = this.filteringObservable.map(data => {
    return _.take(data, this.take);
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="sales-container" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" (scrolled)="this.onScroll()">
  <app-sales-item *ngFor="let sale of this.sales | async" [sale]="sale"></app-sales-item>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're accumulations items like 10, 20, 30, 40,.. but you always want to show only the last batch?

Comment: btw, this looks more like a problem because you're not using `trackBy` in your `*ngFor`. See https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#syntax

Comment: @martin No, I want to add 10 more items whenever I scroll to bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve, I have multiple lists which acts like this.

First of all you want to use some sort of lib, I use 
[ngx-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll).

Then you want your list to use it:

```
<ul infiniteScroll (scrolled)="getItems()">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy:trackByFn">{{item}}</li>
</ul>

trackByFn(i: number, item) {
  return item.<unique-key>;
}
```

Next you want to react to the scroll, do this via the `scrolled` listener as shown above.

Now, what you need for an infinite list to work properly is for each item to have a unique key. You also need the total amount of items available for the list, and the number of items that are currently being shown.

Here is a function I use for this, if you're not using an API to fetch more results you can tweak it to your liking.

```
// isReset decides whether to set offset to 0 or not
getItems(isReset = false): void {

    if (!isReset && this.items.length >= this.total) {
      return;
    }

    this.api.get<CustomResponse>('my-api-endpoint', {
      limit: 10,
      offset: isReset ? 0 : this.items.length,
    })
      .pipe(
        first(),
        tap((res) => this.total = res.totalsize || 0),
        map((res) => res.list)
      )
      .subscribe((items) => {

        // This bit prevents the same batch to be loaded into the list twice if you scroll too fast
        if (this.items.length && !isReset) {

          if (items[items.length - 1].<unique-key> === this.items[this.items.length - 1].<unique-key>) {
            return;
          }
        }

        this.items = isReset ? items : [...this.items, ...items];
      })
    );
  }
```

Make sure to replace `<unique-key>` with a unique key of each item.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we are doing this using Angular 5 and WebApi as server side. We have implemented some kind of sorting in our tables but you can use just part with scrolling and use it on your list. Also we are taking all data from tables and then sending it to clients in chuncks of 10, but if you need speed, you can page your data in SQL server and take only 10 rows at a time. If you need logic for that kind of paging just let me know.

### HTML

```
<div #scb id="scb" class="scrollBarClass" *ngIf="sales && sales.length" (scroll)="onScroll()">
    <div class="table table-striped table-responsive table-sm table-bordered">
        <table class="table" *ngIf="sales && sales.length">
        // here goes you table structure, headers, body and so...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.scrollBarClass {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

### Angular component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('scb') grid: ElementRef;
scroll = false;
page = 1; 
total = 0;   

onScroll() {
    if (this.grid.nativeElement.scrollHeight - this.grid.nativeElement.scrollTop < 510 && this.scroll == false) {
        if (this.sales.length == this.total) {
            return;
        }
        let p: any;
        this.page++;
        this.scroll = true;
        this._myService.searchSales(this.page, 10, this.sortType, this.sortAD)
            .subscribe(
                (data) => { p = data['data']; this.total = data['count']},
                error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error; this.page--; },
                () => {
                    this.scroll = false;
                    Array.prototype.push.apply(this.sales, p);
                });
    }
}
```

### Angular service

```
searchSales(page: number, recperpage: number, sorttype: string, sortad: string) {
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('page', page.toString())
        .append('recperpage', recperpage.toString())
        .append('sorttype', sorttype)
        .append('sortad', sortad);
    return this._http.get<any[]>('sales/searchsales', { params: params });
}
```

### WebAPI controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult searchsales(int page, int recperpage, string sorttype, string sortad)
{
    try
    {
        var count = 0;
        var r = _salesService.SearchSales(sorttype, sortad, ref count);
        return Ok(new { data=r.Skip((page - 1) * recperpage).Take(recperpage).ToList(), count });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return InternalServerError(e);
    }
}
```

### WebAPI service

```
public List<Sales> SearchSales(string sorttype, string sortad, ref int count)
{
    var query = "";

    query = " select * FROM Sales "+
            " ORDER BY " + ((sorttype == null) ? "DateOfSale" : sorttype) + " " + ((sortad == null) ? "DESC" : sortad);
    var result = SQLHelper.ExecuteReader(query);
    count = result.Count;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use for this scenario:

```ts
private filterModel: FilterModel = new FilterModel();
private page: number = 0;

items: ResultModel[] = [];

public onScroll(): void {

  if (this.scrolling) {
    return;
  }
  this.scrolling = true;
  this.page++;

  this.service.loadStuff(this.filterModel, this.page).subscribe(items => {
      !items || !items.length
        ? this.page--
        : items.forEach(item => this.items.push(item));
      this.scrolling = false;
    },
    () => this.scrolling = false);
}
```

Where `filterModel` is an object holding the data about what to load and how to load it - page size, property filters and so on.

If you want to accomplish this in a more RxJs way, you can try something like this (not tested, adjust to your needs):

```ts
private filterModel: FilterModel = new FilterModel();
private filter$ = new Subject<FilterModel>();

private page: number = 0;
private page$ = new Subject<number>();

private cache: ResultModel[][] = [];

items$: Observable<ResultModel>;

ngOnInit() {

  const filter$ = this.filter$.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => this.cache = []),
    map(model => ({ model: this.filterModel = model, page: 0 }))
  );
  const page$ = this.page$.pipe(
    map(pageNumber => ({ model: this.filterModel, page: pageNumber }))
  );

  this.items$ = merge(page$, filter$).pipe(
    startWith({ model: this.filterModel, page: this.page }),
    tap(() => this.scrolling = true)
    mergeMap(({ model: FilterModel, page: number }) => 
      this.service.loadStuff(model, page).pipe(
        tap(response => this.cache[page] = response.items)
      )
    ),
    tap(response => ... ), // Do whatever else with your response here
    map(() => _.flatMap(this.cache)),
    tap(() => this.scrolling = false)
  );
}

onScroll() {
  this.page$.next(this.page++);
}

onFilter(model: FilterModel){
  this.filter$.next(model);
}
```

Hope this steers you the right way :)